# For filters with impulse responses on a specific $x[n]$, how do you calculate DFT of $y[n]$?

Tags: filters, discrete-signals, fourier-transform, linear-systems

Basically I'm talking about N-point moving average/difference filters and not one where $\delta[n]=k$. For example given say a two-point moving average filter:

$$h[n] = \dfrac{\delta[n]+\delta[n-1]}{2} $$

and a defined input signal like

$$x[n] = \sin[2 \pi n]$$

$x(n)$ is discrete and the window size = the period size.

How would you find $Y_k$ (the coefficients of the DFT of $y[n]$)?

Comment: Your input signal doesn't make sense: $x[n]=\sin(2\pi x)$. What is $x$ on the right-hand side? If you mean $x[n]=\sin(2\pi n)$ then it still doesn't make much sense because that signal would be zero for all values of $n$.

Comment: @MattL. is right. Flyingtiger, can you correct your question? The way it is asked now, it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Okay done. Now I thought in discrete time δ[n] = 1 at 0 and 0 elsewhere. So would my filter be 1/2 at zero and 1, and zero elsewhere (the actual vector that I plug into fft)

Comment: no, this signal $x[n] = 0\, \forall n$, because $\sin(0)=0$ and $\sin$ is $2\pi$-periodic.

Comment: Also, I don't think you're using $\delta$ correctly; you can't say $\delta[n] = k$; per definition, in continuous math, $\delta(x=0) \ne c,\,\forall c \in \mathbb R$, and in discrete math, it's usual that $\delta[0] = 1$.

Comment: I believe I understand x[n] but I still don't understand how to take the DFT of the the filter I used h[n] to get Hk? What would my h[n] values be for say N = 2?

Answer (score 1):

> How would you find Yk (the coefficients of the DFT of y(n))?

By applying the DFT to Y.

So: math.

Mathematically, you filter something with a FIR by convolving the signal with the taps vector:

$$y = x * h$$

Hence, the DFT of $y$ becomes is:

$$\mathcal F \{y\} = \mathcal F \left\{ x * h \right\}$$

and thanks to the properties of the DFT, convolution in time domain becomes multiplication in frequency domain:

$$\mathcal F \{y\} = \mathcal F \{ x\}  \mathcal F \{ h \}$$

So you just apply the DFT to both your signal and your taps vector and multiply.

Seriously, this is very basic DFT theory, and you will learn that if you continue your studies of the discrete Fourier transform.

Comment: So you have to calculate y(n) first? I thought there was a way you could get from x(n) to Xk to Yk? This is assuming i have no idea what y(n), just the given impulse response and x.

Comment: Of course there is a way and it's even in the answer: 1) Calculate $X_k$ from x(n), calculate $H_k$ from h(n) and multiply the two. That's $Y_k$.

Comment: That would be true only if you used *cyclic* convolution, but that's not what a filter normally does. The DFT of the filtered signal does not generally equal the product of the DFTs of $x$ and $h$. This is only the case if you zero pad $x$ as well as $h$ to the length of $y$, which is `length(x)+length(h)-1`.

Comment: As @MattL. says, you need to be careful multiplying DFTs. Otherwise you may end up with odd end effects (or worse).

Comment: @PeterK. of course, that's right -- however if you know what you're doing and use the right windows of your input signal, using FFT filters is not only possible but also [state of the art](https://gnuradio.org/doc/doxygen/classgr_1_1filter_1_1kernel_1_1fft__filter__ccc.html).

Comment: @MarcusMüller: Ha! State of the art my.... er rear end.  They've been used that way for a long time, and have big problems when it comes to latency. [See Bill Gardner's paper on how to do filtering with zero latency.](http://www.cs.ust.hk/mjg_lib/bibs/DPSu/DPSu.Files/Ga95.PDF)

Comment: @PeterK., I agree, in low-latency systems, that's not really much of an option. If you're doing your filter with 10s of MS/s in a PC, however, the latency of the FFT won't matter that much, anymore. I'll read that article later today; seems interesting. To give you my experiences: I have not been able to measure a significant difference in latency between properly implemented direct form FIRs and FFT filtering, probably because the FFT is so darn fast, and GNU Radio works on sample blocks, anyway. Working on blocks is necessary for performance on general purpose CPU/cache architectures & SMP.

Comment: Understood!  Yes, block-only-based processing will always have a latency of at least one block.  If the blocks are small enough (time-wise) then the latency is not noticeable.  If you're doing high-end audio, though, then that latency is a killer.

Comment: @PeterK. I see... I'm coming from SDR, myself, where latency is often a problem, too. Luckily, the modern communication standards are kind of designed to work with SDR, so there's often larger time windows than there were in earlier standards e.g. to continue transmission before the receiver ACKs things.

Comment: @PeterK: I just tried; a 7227-tap filter, real taps, complex signal. FIR filter latency in the hand-assembly optimized single threaded FIR on x86 SSE4 is avg 8850936 CPU ticks for a block of avg 4092 samples; the same filter as five-threaded FFT filter gives you a latency of avg 132600 CPU ticks per 8158 samples (I intentionally did not restrict the output chunk sizes to allow maximum throughput rather than min latency) -- the FFT approach has a latency that's lower by about two orders of magnitude by being so much faster for this gigantic filter.

Comment: @PeterK: For a 73-tap filter, however, the FFT filter takes about twice as much time as the FIR, but prefers to produce twice the amount of samples per call.

Comment: Cool!  The FFT is definitely going to be faster for longer filter lengths. Still, all you really need is for your processing (whether FFT or not) to take less time than your sample period. If you can compute the next output sample from the current input sample (and its history) before it's needed, then there is zero latency regardless of the algorithm.

Comment: @PeterK. huh, sub sample period processing? If you can do that, you should definitely increase the sample rate ;P No seriously, that is the ASIC/FPGA kind of thing. For example, inside the Ettus USRP (universal software radio peripheral) X300, the samples come in at 200MS/s. Of course, at these rates, you can't do much in less than a sample period -- you already have to heavily pipeline every operation so that things run at sample clock speeds at all.

Comment: @PeterK. I could imagine that's different for audio rates, which would be < 1/1000 of that; considering that the huge FFT filter took about 16 cycles per (complex!) sample, doing a few hundred kilosamples per second wouldn't be a problem, implying that for shorter filters, you get sub-sampling period latency.

Comment: RIght.  Audio is only 48kS/s or 96kS/s, which is a much easier time to do things in. :-) 200MS/s is harder. ;-)  The guys at Lake DSP (now part of Dolby)  were doing zero latency 256k-tap FIR filters 20+ years ago.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/28897/discussion-between-marcus-muller-and-peter-k).

Comment: DSP.SE won't log me into chat! It keeps saying that it's offline for maintenance.... :-(

Comment: @PeterK. that's strange; considering you're even a mod, have you reported this (e.g. on Meta.dsp.... or the "contact us" link)? I just said that doing that is pretty cool and rolled a bit in nostalgia :D